# switch over template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, macros

When the value of a template parameter of a function is known only at run time, one has to write a code that consider all possible parameters, and accordingly call the function.

This (over-)simplified example illustrate the problem

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i>
void f()
{
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   std::cin >> i;
   if (i==0)
      f<0>();
   else if (i==1)
      f<1>();
   else if (i==2)
      f<2>();
   else
      std::cout << "invalid input" << std::endl;
}
```

This is obviously very tedious, especially if there are many possible values. Even worse, if the template parameters are more than 1, one needs to consider all combinations, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i, bool X>
void f()
{
   std::cout << i << ' ';
   if constexpr (X)
      std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   char c;

   std::cin >> i;
   std::cin >> c;    
   if (c == 'y')
      {
         if (i==0)
            f<0,true>();
         else if (i==1)
            f<1,true>();
         else if (i==2)
            f<2,true>();
         else
            std::cout << "invalid input" << std::endl;
      }
   else
      {
         if (i==0)
            f<0,false>();
         else if (i==1)
            f<1,false>();
         else if (i==2)
            f<2,false>();
         else
            std::cout << "invalid input" << std::endl;
      }
}
```

(I am of course aware that abusing of this idea, i.e., instantiate `f` for all template combinations, may lead to code bloat.)

I am looking for a macro that allows to "essentially" write something equivalent to `f<i, x>()` with `i` and `x` some run-time variables.

To be more specific, assuming a finite set of values for all template parameters, say

```
i = i1, i2, ... , in
x = x1, x2, ... , xn
```

I would like a macro that translate something like this

```
CallF(f, i, {i1,...,in}, x, {x1,...,xn}, par...)
```

into

```
if (i==i1)
{
    if (x==x1)
      f<i1,x1>(par...);
    else if (x==x2)
      f<i1,x2>(par...);
    ....
}
else if (i==i2)
{
    if (x==x1)
      f<i2,x1>(par...);
    else if (x==x2)
      f<i2,x2>(par...);
    ....
}
else if (i==i3)
....
```

Comment: Using an array/matrix/map might also do the job (`std::array<void(*)(), 3> funcs[] = {&f<0>, &f<1>, &f<2>}; if (i < 3) { funcs[i]();}`). That array might even be constructed programmatically

Comment: As written in the question, this is a simplified example. I am looking for is a way to "automatize" the writing of code that exhaust all allowed values of template parameters.

Comment: If you need something like this, those template non-type arguments should probably be regular function arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do that for 1 template argument:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

template <int i>
void f(char const* s, bool b, double d) {
  std::printf("%d -> %s %d %f\n", i, s, b, d);
}

template <class T, class ...Args>
[[noreturn]] void call_f(T&&, Args&&...) {
  throw std::invalid_argument{"Argument not in the list"};
}

template <auto first, auto... rest, class T, class ...Args>
void call_f(T const& t, Args&&... args) {
  if (t == first)
    f<first>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  else
    call_f<rest...>(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
  int i = 2; // template argument

  // other arguments for f
  char const* s = "Hello";
  bool b = false;
  double d = 3.14;

  // decide which one to call at run time.
  call_f<1, 2, 3>(i, s, b, d);
}
```